# Downloading pdfs on a webpage using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to download the PDFs from this [website](https://reporting.standardbank.com/debt-investors/debt-securities/debt-securities/), however the code that I have below is only returning NAs when trying to retrieve the PDF links from the page.

I think that there is a step that I am missing that looks for the pdf links within the tables on the page. As an example, these sections, expand to show the specific documents that I want to download, but I am unable to access them with the first call to extract the links.

[image]

[image]

```
# Load the packages
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)

# Scrape the website
url <- "https://reporting.standardbank.com/debt-investors/debt-securities/debt-securities/"
html <- read_html(url)

# Extract the links to the PDFs
pdf_links <- html_nodes(html, "a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_extract("(?<=\\.pdf).+")

# Download the PDFs
pdf_links %>%
  map(function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
```

Comment: You have  stated _"pdf links within the tables"_  (which is what Tom's answer provides) and then describe 4 sections that do include tables + 1 section that actually includes a list. By "table" do you mean HTML table or everything that might look like a table? 
And there are other tables with pdf links on the page, you want those excluded?  BTW, you get NAs because you are attempting to extract everything that follows `.pdf` , up to that point you have a vector of valid links, though it's likely with some unwanted extras.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://reporting.standardbank.com/debt-investors/debt-securities/debt-securities/#1535044558978-07920fd6-5fa1" %>% 
  read_html() %>%  
  html_elements(".table a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: The above works for the given website, but unfortunately falls over when the same approach is applied to another website with almost the same layout. It would be helpful to revisit this answer that has a better explanation and can apply more generally. The above doesn't work for this page for example: https://www.nedbank.co.za/content/nedbank/desktop/gt/en/investor-relations/debt-investor/debt-investors-programme.html

Comment: @AveshenPillay , I'm sorry, but the page linked in comment has nothing in common with the one in the question and it requires an entirely different approach ( content of tables is embedded in json responses and those are requested by javascript). Scarping **is** mostly site-specific.

Comment: @AveshenPillay The scope of the question for not for multiple sites, and there is no one-solution fits all kinda code that can be applied universally. And there is no explanation needed for my answer I feel, you used "a" tag, while I used ".table a". I literally just added a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a general method using Selenium in R.

```
# Install and load the required libraries
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)

# Start a headless browser
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4445L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "108.0.5359.71")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Go to the website and get the HTML content
url <- "https://www.nedbank.co.za/content/nedbank/desktop/gt/en/investor-relations/debt-investor/debt-investors-programme.html"
remDr$navigate(url)
html <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

# Find all the links on the page
links <- html_nodes(html, "a")

# Extract the href attributes of the links
hrefs <- html_attr(links, "href")

# Keep only the links that end in ".pdf"
pdf_links <- hrefs[grepl(".pdf$", hrefs)]

# Print the PDF links
pdf_links

# Close the browser
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
```